# HTML table column width not consistent

Tags: html, css

How can I set the html table width to be consistent. For example on below jsbin, column 1,2,4 and 5 are having row span 1 and column span 2 but why the column width of 3 and 4 is wider than column 1 and 2.

Sample below:

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;padding:11px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center;width:100px}
.tg .noborder{border-style:none;}
.tg .tg-943m{background-color:#656565}
.tg .tg-7a16{background-color:#fffc9e}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
 .tg {width: auto !important;}
 .tg col {width: auto !important;}
 .tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
```

```html
<div class=tg-wrap><table id=myTable class=tg><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 9 > E </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 9 > C </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-08-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-08-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-08-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-08-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-08-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-08-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-08-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-08-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-08-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-08-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-08-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-08-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-07-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-07-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-07-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-07-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-07-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-07-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-07-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-07-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-07-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-07-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-07-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-07-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-06-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-06-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-06-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-06-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-06-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-06-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-06-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-06-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-06-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-06-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-06-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-06-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-05-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-05-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-05-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-05-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-05-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-05-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-05-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-05-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-05-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-05-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-05-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-05-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-3A-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-3A-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-3A-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-3A-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-3A-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-3A-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-3A-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-3A-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-3A-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-3A-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-3A-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-3A-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-03-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-03-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-03-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-03-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-03-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-03-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-03-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-03-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-03-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-03-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-03-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-03-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-02-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-02-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-02-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-02-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-02-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-02-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-02-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-02-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-02-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-02-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-02-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-02-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-01-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-01-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-01-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-01-38 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-01-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-01-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-01-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-01-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-01-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-01-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-01-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-01-118 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td class=noborder></td></tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-09-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-09-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-09-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-08-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-08-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-08-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-08-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-08-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-07-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-07-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-07-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-07-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-07-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-06-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-06-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-06-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-06-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-06-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-05-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-05-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-05-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-05-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-05-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-3A-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-3A-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-3A-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-3A-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-3A-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-03-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-03-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-03-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-03-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-03-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-02-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-02-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-02-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-02-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-02-128 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-01-118 </td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td class=noborder></td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-08 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-18 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-28 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-38 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-68 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-01-88 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-01-98 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-01-118 </td>
<td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SE-01-128 </td>
</tr></table></div>
```

Sample screen shot as below:
Column 1, 2 4 and 5 having same attribute col span 2, but why in my view the width is not consistent. 
[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0J7E.png)

Sample expected output
[image]
[Original js bin](http://jsbin.com/caqulug/edit?html,output)

Comment: What you should do in cases like this is create a [mcve]; that is, prune the code down to the absolute minimum required to reproduce the issue. Also, in this case you should make a screenshot of what you're seeing. On my computer, columns 1, 2, 4 and 5 are all the same width.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I've added a screen-shot of my view

Comment: Why do you make it so difficult for yourself? Or can't you change the table structure? Just by separating the upper and lower part to their own tables you already make it a lot easier for yourself? Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/887qwed3/ . Then if you need the two tables on the right to align with each other use some wrapper divs to make them align...don't use td's to make space which makes the whole thing just hard to read. Ps. colspans affect the whole table, not just tr's (you need to have same amount of td's or colspans in each tr for them to work.

Comment: Understand that it's tedious, but I'm not able to change the table structure by making it two separate table as this table is maintained only with coordinates as a whole layout. For example, row 1 col 1 "DA-09-09", row 1 col 2 "DA-09-08", row 1 col 3 "DA-09-18" etc. That's the reason I'm using row col span in my table. Is there any other way that I can set the each cell to have a fixed width?So no matter how many col span, the output will not deviate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which columns you want to change.

However the column with the "E" has a colspan of just 1.
This lets the third column of the lower table part span to the half of the top columns.

```
VIRTUAL COLUMNS     |1 2 |3 4 |5 |6 5
TOP COLUMN WIDTHS   |2   |2   |1 |2   
LOWER COLUMNS       |2   |2   |2   |
```

Changing the colspan of the "E"-column to 2 helps here.

Comment: I've added screen-shot on my post. Colspan for "E" is 1 is my requirement. Why column 2 "DA-09-18" and Col 3 "E" is having the same width as per my screen-shot although they have different colspan.

Answer (score 0):

First on your css style you set TD width as 100%. 
Html tables doesn't handle too well percentage widths.

Try setting it to pixels if possible.

```
.tg td{ width:100px }
```

Second you have an empty TR tag on you table line 258, that has no columns and no colspan. That is making your table to break.

And third you have too many columns on the second part of your table.
Try removing 3 of them, or fixing the colspan counts.

```css
<style>
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;padding:11px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center;width:100%}
.tg .tg-943m{background-color:#656565}
.tg .tg-7a16{background-color:#fffc9e}
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
 .tg {width: auto !important;}
 .tg col {width: auto !important;}
 .tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
</style>
```

```html
<div class=tg-wrap>
 <table id=myTable class=tg>
  <tr>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-08 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-18 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 9 > E </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-28 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DA-09-38 </td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-08 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-18 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 1 > SB-09-28 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-38 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-68 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 1 rowspan= 9 > C </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-88 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-98 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DB-09-118 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-08 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-18 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-28 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-38 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-68 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-88 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-98 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DD-09-118 </td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td class=noborder></td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-08 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-18 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-28 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-38 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-68 </td>
   <td nowrap colspan= 2 rowspan= 1 > DE-09-88 </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried changed the table css width to 100px but the output is also not my desired output. For your suggestion on number 3, it's my requirement to have addition 3 column on second part of the table. I've added my desired output.